# Submitting photocopy of English assessment for UK visa

Tags: uk

My proof of English from UK NARIC has not yet been delivered. They have sent a copy by fax however. Can I submit this when applying for a UK visa?

All my other documents are originals.

The guidelines require original copy and a photocopy for all documents submitted. They state also that it is better for applicants to explain if they do not have a document than fake or lie. In my case my start date for work is out and the post could take up to 35 days to deliver the original copy. I have heard people who had their visas granted by submitting the same English certificates that were provided to them by email. In my case the copy was faxed.

Comment: What do the guidelines for the application say?

Comment: Guidelines require original copy nand a photocopy for all documents submitted. They state also that it is better for applicants to explain if they do not have a document than fake or lie. In my case my start date for work is out and the post could take up to 35 days to deliver the original copy. l have heard people who had their visas granted by submitting the same english certificates which were provided to them by email. In my case the copy was faxed.

Comment: I haved edited your comment answer into the text, but can you please [edit] it again and add the **literal** text of the relevant guideline? Your own text *require original copy nand a photocopy* is not clear.

Comment: What visa are you applying for?